# How to refresh bound jTable?

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable

I have `jTable` bound with MySQL table. This way a add new row:

```
    Student student=new Student(3, "Name", "Last name");
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    entityManager.persist(student);
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

But I can't refresh `jTable`, and I don't know how to do this, could anybody help me? I tried to invoke `jTable1.updateUI()`, `jTable1.repaint()`, but it doesn't work for me, I see changes only after application restart.

```
    private void initComponents() {
    bindingGroup = new org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BindingGroup();

    entityManager = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? null : javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("multitimer?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNullPU").createEntityManager();
    StudentsQuery = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? null : entityManager.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Students c");
    StudentsList = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? java.util.Collections.emptyList() : StudentsQuery.getResultList();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    org.jdesktop.swingbinding.JTableBinding jTableBinding = org.jdesktop.swingbinding.SwingBindings.createJTableBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, StudentsList, jTable1);
    org.jdesktop.swingbinding.JTableBinding.ColumnBinding columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${id}"));
    columnBinding.setColumnName("Id");
    columnBinding.setColumnClass(Integer.class);
    columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${descr}"));
    columnBinding.setColumnName("Descr");
    columnBinding.setColumnClass(String.class);
    columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${guid}"));
    columnBinding.setColumnName("Guid");
    columnBinding.setColumnClass(String.class);
    bindingGroup.addBinding(jTableBinding);

    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);

    jButton1.setText("jButton1");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 275, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
    );

    bindingGroup.bind();

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>
```

Comment: And you're certain that the jtable pulls / contains the latest data after the commit occurs?

Comment: I'm not sure about jTable, but in MySQL changes exist and I need to see it in jTable.

Comment: Clearly you commit the change, so of course MySQL is going to be updated, but you'll need to repopulate / update the DATA in the JTable, not just repaint it. Unless you're using some super fancy extension of JTable that syncs itself with a database table (which sounds like what you're trying to write). How are you intially populating the table?

Comment: What is your code to populate the JTable the first time (before adding a new student)? Does it contain any data? What about the TableModel?

Comment: `but in MySQL changes exist and I need to see it in jTable` - I would guess you also need to update the TableModel with the new Student object.

Comment: my code was generated by netbeans:

Comment: added initComponents() to answer.

Comment: how can i update tableModel?

Comment: Even initComponents() call doesn't update jTable.

Answer (score 1):

With the binding and AutoUpdater in place all you should have to do is adding the new object to the bound collection.

`studentsList.add(student);`

Make sure you use `ObservableCollections.observableList()` when initializing the collection `studentsList`.